# ¿Cómo verificar si un dato llega como lista o como arreglo en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un problema con un código en flutter, donde tengo un

```dart
String cosa= aux_cosa['imagen']['url']
```

Resulta que de la respuesta de mi api, puede llegar

`imagen:{"url":"......."}` u otras veces vacío de la siguiente manera `imagen:[]`, quiere decir que mi respuesta no tiene imagen. De la forma  como lo declaro se me visualizan mis datos de las imágenes, y de las que no tiene me dice

> type'String ' is not a subtype of type int of 'index'

Por lo que entiendo debe verificar cuando llega como lista y cuando llega como arreglo. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega más código para poder entender el contexto

Comment: DIego en la primera imagen es mi respuesta con imagen, en la segunda sin imagen, en la tercera este el codigo y en la cuarta es el mensaje que aparece cuando esta sin imagen.

Comment: Podrías poner en vez de la 2da y 3era imagen, ponerlo como código? no todos podemos ver las imagenes

Comment: Maria, antes que nada parece que tienes un error tipográfico por que la clave no parece ser `imagen` sino `imagenes`, por otro lado es poco consistente de parte de la API que cierta vez retorne una lista vacía y otra vez un objeto tipo Map, comparte el código con el que estás inicializando `aux_cosa`. Y como te dijeron, copia el código como texto. Suerte

Answer (score 0):

tienes dos problemas,

1- La manera en que formulas la pregunta, queda poco clara, y es más complicado que alguien te de una respuesta rápido si no eres concisa en el error.

2- Con respecto al código, antes de asignar el valor de:

```
String cosa = aux_cosa['imagen']['url']
```

Necesitas verificar que aux_cosa['imagen'] existe, esto lo puedes hacer con un condicional "If", donde le indiques lo siguiente,

```
if (!aux_cosa['imagen'))
    return error; // o lo que quieras
```

Ya luego de hacer la verificación podrás hacer la asignación sin fallo alguno.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! El siguiente ejemplo te puede servir para saber que tipo es el que estas recibiendo:

```
final dynamic data1 = [];
print(data1 is List); // true
final dynamic data2 = {"url": "url"};
print(data2 is List); // false
```